# Search functionality for an Asp.net gridview without using database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint-2013

I am using a gridview and bind data to it from a SharePoint list.

I want to know how to use search functionality for my gridview as I don't have any database. (and the solutions I see all use a database)

Is there any other solution apart from the JQuery plug-in DataTables??

Kindly Help! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to search through sharepoint list, not gridview.

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists["list"];
            string title = "line for search";
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(new SPQuery()
            {
                Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + title + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
            });
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                mygrid.DataSource = items.GetDataTable();
                mygrid.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use SPGridView instead of normal Asp.net Gridview when you specially working with SharePoint, into SPGridView you are able to access Filter property which is not exactly same as Search but apart from the "JQuery plug-in DataTables" it is far better.

```
spGV.FilterDataFields = "Year,Title,,Name";
spGV.FilteredDataSourcePropertyName = "FilterExpression";
```

[image]

you can find complete Example here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SPGRIDVIEW-EXAMPLE-47276dd4